# Deduplication of rows that almost the same in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery, duplicates

I have a table in BigQuery that each row in the table contains one article and its related info.

For the same article, there are duplicated rows. However, the rows are exactly the same besides they have a different acquisition date.

I would like to know how to deduplicate and keep any of the acquisition dates is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the rows are exactly the same besides they have a different acquisition date
>   ... how to deduplicate and keep any of the acquisition dates is fine

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(acquisitionDate) FROM UNNEST([t])))
```

You can test above approach with **totally simplified dummy data** as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'aaa' info, 1 acquisitionDate UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'aaa', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ccc', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ccc', 4
)
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(acquisitionDate) FROM UNNEST([t])))
```

with output

```
Row id  info    acquisitionDate  
1   1   aaa     1    
2   2   ccc     3
```

In case if you need to preserve let's say most recent acquisitionDate - you can use below version:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY acquisitionDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(acquisitionDate) FROM UNNEST([t])))
```

this would return below

```
Row id  info    acquisitionDate  
1   1   aaa     2    
2   2   ccc     4
```

Finally, if you need to preserve all acquisition Dates - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY acquisitionDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
  ARRAY_AGG(acquisitionDate) acquisitionDates
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST([(SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(acquisitionDate) FROM UNNEST([t]))]) x
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', x)
```

which outputs

```
Row id  info    acquisitionDates     
1   1   aaa     1    
                2    
2   2   ccc     3    
                4
```